# Make All Bootstrap Thumbnails The Same Size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How would I go about making the bootstrap thumbnails the same size but keep the responsiveness of the images, keep images from stretching, and filling the thumbnail space to full. Overflow: hidden is okay though. I've tried several things but to no avail.

```
 See http://codepen.io/zepzia/pen/vyPZjK
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my Codepen, i forked yours http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQbmmR
The best I could think of without ruining the pictures (since they are different ratios) is it simply add a max-height;

```
img{
  max-height:190px
}
```

I also changed your ng-repeat code slightly.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="x in recipes | filter:  search">
```

I added a col-lg and changed your col-md to 6.  works fine with the images you have.

Comment: this is problematic as it doesn't filled the thumbnail space and if the max-height exceeds shorter images then the images are again not the same height.